# Do I need to use multiple databases in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am designing a CRM using Ruby on Rails. How do you think, do I need a separate database for every client company? Or should I use the same database for everyone?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't. Why would you?

Comment: Every company would have its data in a separate database. More secure and faster.

Comment: Is it faster when you need to do JOIN queries as well?

Comment: Why would you need to JOIN data from separate companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are separate companies or competing companies (for say a white label CRM) you'll most definitely want to run separate instances because then you can credibly claim total sandboxing. Otherwise, if you ever inadvertently wrote code that somehow allowed the data from one to display for the other, the game is over. Your customer will run for the hills and tell everyone about their terrible experience with your product.

I would even suggest you run separate instances of your app for each customer. Heroku provides a super simple way to deploy RoR apps so spinning up a new one whenever you add a new customer is a reasonable approach. Of course, if you want a more turnkey solution that allows people to just sign up for an account, you will have to have a single instance that enforces customer data sandboxing in code. Obviously it can be done, but the separation isn't done at the infrastructure level which is ultimately the safest way.

Best regards.

Comment: Well said. Just want to add aside from the security standpoint and separation of data, this would also lead to smaller tables. When you get a lot of data, managing the indexes can be a bit heavy.

Comment: @MattLong Also, I can use the same database but different tables, right? I mean something like table [company_name]_records, which will be different for every company.

Answer (score 2):

I do it with a single database, like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records

  def recent_records
   records.desc(:created_at)
  end
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Then, in the controller, I can write:

```
@records = @company.recent_records
```

And pass that down to the views.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like a less secure, less scalable, and less performant solution than using separate DBs and App Instances for each customer.

Comment: Without numbers, I can't comment on that. This will work well for a large number of apps. The OP asked a general rails question, not a scaling question. Early optimization is the root of all evil, or so goes the saying.